# Android System Webview 46.x 302 Redirect

Tags: android, redirect, webview

The last version of the android system webview cant redirect with status code 302. The onpagestarted method in the webviewclient is called twice but the onpagefinished or the onreceivederror methods arent called.
If i set the redirect status code on 301 the redirect works correctly.

I use the following device with following software versions:

- HTC M9
- Android 5.1
- Android System WebView 46.0.2490.28

With the android system webview 45.0.2454.87 it works correct.

I think thats a bug in the 46.x version of the android system webview.

Here is a link to the issue which i posted:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=533440

Any suggestions how to resolve this problem?

**Edit:**
I figured out why this happens and open a new issue:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=534758

Comment: links broken, how solved the problem ?

Comment: It was an webview bug and is fixed in version 47.XX